# sphinx "autodoc-skip-member" with deprecated decorator

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Trying to exclude deprecated decorated members/functions from my sphinx documentation:

So far I have the following in sphinx/conf.py:

```
  # try to exclude deprecated                                                     
def maybe_skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):                     
    if hasattr(obj, "func_dict") and "__deprecated__" in obj.func_dict:         
       print "skipping " + name                                                 
       return True                                                              
    return skip or False                                                        

def setup(app):                                                                 
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', maybe_skip_member)
```

The decorator sets the "**deprecated**" value to True in func_dict.

During the sphinx-build, it outputs all of the desired function names (print "skipping" + name). But they still show up in the final document, but without a docstring. My intention was, that those members are really skipped out.

How to achieve the desired behaviour (really kick out those decorated functions)?

If you need additional information, please request it:)